# how do I enable mongodb cli pretty print? - db.col.find().pretty() not working

Tags: mongodb

Using mongo v2.4.5 shell, db.col.find().pretty() does not pretty print for me on either osx console or linux ubuntu 12.04 bash.

There is no diff in the output with and without pretty()

```
> db.people.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("520d293752cfe6ece5d3fd77"), "name" : "Andrew" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("520e448b77803f8f15fcfedb"), "name" : "Amy" }
> 
> db.people.find().pretty()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("520d293752cfe6ece5d3fd77"), "name" : "Andrew" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("520e448b77803f8f15fcfedb"), "name" : "Amy" }
>
```

What am I missing?  (something crazy basic no doubt)

Thx

---

UPDATE:  doh! answered below.  I had not realized such a simple doc would not be prettified.  Nested docs pretty fine for me.

Comment: If you add a third field to your document (for example, `{ _id: (...), "name" : "Andrew", age: 40 }`), this documents will be printed pretty when you call `pretty()`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`.pretty` will only really change things when you have nested or larger documents:

```
> db.so.insert( { name: "Derick" } );
> db.so.insert( { f: 'Derick', s: 'Rethans', t: 'derickr' } );
> db.so.insert( { name: { f: 'Derick', s: 'Rethans' } } );

> db.so.find();
{ "_id" : ObjectId("520e49a21d7b77441eaf6446"), "name" : "Derick" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("520e49b11d7b77441eaf6447"), "name" : { "f" : "Derick", "s" : "Rethans" } }

> db.so.find().pretty();
{ "_id" : ObjectId("520e49a21d7b77441eaf6446"), "name" : "Derick" }
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("520e4f895a4563e39f06b030"),
    "f" : "Derick",
    "s" : "Rethans",
    "t" : "derickr"
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("520e49b11d7b77441eaf6447"),
    "name" : {
        "f" : "Derick",
        "s" : "Rethans"
    }
}
```

So I presume it works just fine for you!

Comment: `pretty()` doesn't change  documents which have <3 fields (as I found by experimenting). If your document will have 3 fields - it will be prettified. But not only documents with nested objects

Answer (score 2):

You can add these lines to your file in `$HOME/.mongorc.js` in order to enable pretty print.

```
DBQuery.prototype._prettyShell = true
```

Alternatively, you can use this command that prints docs in array format:

```
db.collection.find().toArray()
```

cheers!

Comment: This wouldn't help. `pretty()` does the same thing: `function (){
    this._prettyShell = true;
    return this;
}`

Comment: @SergeyGavruk He isn't wrong. You don't have to append `pretty()` to each command with his first solution

Comment: @callmekatootie, I know. I said that this wouldn't help because of this comment http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18277129/how-do-i-enable-mongodb-cli-pretty-print-db-col-find-pretty-not-working/18277285?noredirect=1#comment26810566_18277359