# What is the correct way to use find().pretty() for this collection

Tags: mongodb

I need to use find().pretty() to get the values for svalue and units but i am not sure how to write it correctly any help with syntax would be appreciated.

```
"IOT" : {
    "measurements" : {
        "meas_id" : "1",
        "sensor_id" : "223344",
        "svalue" : "22.3344",
        "units" : "DEG",
        "dt_measured" : "20190403T154653Z",
        "lat" : "533244",
        "long" : "60446.0"
    }
```

Comment: possible duplicate - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18277129/how-do-i-enable-mongodb-cli-pretty-print-db-col-find-pretty-not-working

Comment: Im only looking for certain parts of the collection is that similar? sorry new to mongo

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3985214/retrieve-only-the-queried-element-in-an-object-array-in-mongodb-collection

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
db.<table_name>.find({},{"IOT.measurements.svalue":"","IOT.measurements.units":""}).pretty()
```

This will return `svalue` and `units` along with `_id` only. if you dont want `_id`
u can set `_id:false`. Like this

```
  db.<table_name>.find({},{_id:false,"IOT.measurements.svalue":"","IOT.measurements.units":""}).pretty()
```

Comment: Thank you for the response!, for my case db.measurements.find({},{IOT.measurements.svalue:"",IOT.measurements.units:""}).pretty() should be correct? This gives me a syntax error

Comment: can u post a screenshot or copy paste where exactly are u getting error

Comment: db.measurements.find({},{IOT.measurements.svalue:"",IOT.measurements.units:""}).pretty()
2019-04-24T19:30:22.976+0100 E QUERY    [js] SyntaxError: missing : after property id @(shell):1:28

Answer (score 0):

To achieve expected result, use below option of find and use '0' to exclude column and '1' to include columns in output

```
db.measurements.find({},{"IOT.measurements.svalue":1,"IOT.measurements.units":1}).pretty()
```